# Phaser 3 animation frame offset?

Tags: phaser-framework

I am using multiatlas and json file for my sprites in Phaser 3. How can I set an offset (like `setOrigin`) *for specific frames*?

There are some properties in the json which I suppose may help, but I don't understand their meaning. What's the difference between `sourceSize` and `spriteSourceSize`? I have also seen `anchor` property, but I suspect it's an old Phaser version...

The best alternative would be if it was possible to set the frame offset *in the animation definition* itself, and not in the json definition of frames. But is it possible?

Comment: How did you create the multiatlas files?

Comment: @brae: I used a special combination: leshylabs.com/apps/sstool/ (JSON-TP-Array format) + some TexturePacker-style formatting at the beginning and end of the file. (I can't make it work with the leshylabs tool alone, but don't want to pay for the Texture Packer.)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: nevermind, I misunderstood the question. It's about animation frames and `setOrigin`, and wether the `setOrigin` can be different for different frames. AFIAK all animation sprites get the same origin, so the same "anchor", but I'm not 100% sure about this.

v--old answer--v

Wait, are you storing the animation-sequence in the sprite json file? If so, I'd like to know how you do that, because AFAIK you have to create the animation sequences programmatically in JavaScript, I usually do that in the preloader:

```
// preloader scene
create: function ()
{
    // create animations
    this.anims.create({
            key: 'anim_run',
            frames: [
                { key: 'sprites', frame: 'guyrun1' },
                { key: 'sprites', frame: 'guyrun2' },
                { key: 'sprites', frame: 'guyrun3' },
                { key: 'sprites', frame: 'guyrun2' }
            ],
            frameRate: 15,
            repeat: -1
        });

    //..etc.
},
```

And you can start the animation with a startFrame parameter to offset the animation, i.e. start at a frame other than the first frame, like so

```
// start animation with random offset
var r = Phaser.Math.RND.between(0, 3);
mainguy.play('anim_run', null, r); // key, ignoreIfPlaying = null, startFrame = r
```

Comment: I didn't say a was storing *animation* in json. I am storing *frames* for the animation in json, and want to know how to create an offset for some of them. (For example, in a frame where a dude is jumping, the y-offset would be positive.) This could be possibly done either in the json definition of the frames, or in the animation definition. I am asking if someone knows how.